# How do you integrate Visual Studio Web tests in TFS 2017 U2?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Installed TFS 2017 U2 and I can see one of new features is that Visual Studio Test is one of the available tasks in Release management but I can not find any guidance how to integrate Visual Studio webtests into that. Is it possible now properly incoporate WebTest straight up from TFS UI?

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resource recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Visual Studio Test task is using `vstest.console.exe` to execute tests which is documented at [VSTest.Console.exe Command-Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796(v=vs.110).aspx).

To run a web test you need to use Visual Studio and `MSTest.exe`. For more tutorial about the integration of web test and TFS, you could refer below links:

- [Guide to get started with Visual Studio Web Load Testing and
  Automation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edwinh/2016/04/21/guide-to-get-started-with-visual-studio-web-load-testing-and-automation-2/)
- [Running WebTests as part of a VSTS VNext Release pipeline](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2016/05/30/Running-WebTests-as-part-of-a-VSTS-VNext-Release-pipeline)